# What is the difference between Flex Library and ActionScript Library?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

What is the difference between Flex Library and ActionScript Library (Flash Builder 4.7)?

Comment: The "possible duplicate" listed in the question is a completely different question.  I voted to re-open.  A Flex Library [project] is one that has all the Flex libraries in the classpath; whereas an ActionScript library project will not.

Answer (score 0):

Flex refers to the components that Adobe ships. Actionscript is the language. Therefore a Flex library would be one that contains code that either uses or extends Flex components, whereas an Actionscript library will be one that does not.